# jQuery Toggle Text Based on Element Visibility Not Behaving as Expected

Tags: jquery

Example fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/S6CwT/

**CSS**

```
#service_container {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="/services/update/8" id="view_service">View Service Record</a>

<div id="service_container">
    Test
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(function() {

    // toggle visibility of service section
    jQuery('#view_service').click(function() {
        jQuery('#service_container').slideToggle('slow');
        // toggle text
        if (jQuery('#service_container').is(':visible')) {
            jQuery('#view_service').text('Hide Service Record');
        } else {
            jQuery('#view_service').text('View Service Record');
        }
        return false
    });

});
```

The bug is when clicking the link for the first time, the link text will change correctly to say  `Hide Service Record` but on subsequent clicks the text will not change to `Show Service Record` when the  `div` is hidden and back to `Hide Service Record` when the container is visible again.

Must be something silly I'm not spotting but can't see what I've done wrong.

I tried it the opposite way using `is(:hidden)` but that behaves the same way.

Comment: have you trid putting the if statement inside a callback from the slideToggle?

Comment: slidetoogle makes display none/block so get css display attribute and compare it with none or block and accordingly show the text

Comment: @Coop no but thinking about it now, that's probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (jQuery('#view_service').html()=="View Service Record") {
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/S6CwT/2/

I compare html of `#view_service`

Comment: this was the best answer for me, @Anton's also worked but I was getting some FOUC whereas with this there wasn't any of that and the toggle was still in place.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
jQuery(function() {

     jQuery("#service_container").hide();
     // toggle visibility of service section
     jQuery('#view_service').click(function()
     {
         // toggle text
         if (jQuery('#service_container').is(':visible'))
         {
             jQuery('#view_service').text('View Service Record');
         } 
         else 
         {
             jQuery('#view_service').text('Hide Service Record');
         }
         jQuery('#service_container').slideToggle('slow');

         return false
    });

});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S6CwT/4/)

Answer (score 1):

try to use "on" event for future changes on any event as below

```
 jQuery('#view_service').on("click",function() {

             // your code..
}
```

Comment: thanks, behaviour is still the same though, would've been surprised if it worked as it's not a new DOM element, it's just the same one but with different text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, show/hide in the if statement

```
   if (jQuery('#service_container').is(':visible')) {
       jQuery(this).text('View Service Record');
       jQuery('#service_container').hide('slow');
   } else {
       jQuery(this).text('Hide Service Record');
       jQuery('#service_container').show('slow');
   }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S6CwT/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the '#service_container' is visible when the question is asked because it's not invisible until after the `slideToggle()` completes. One solution would be to pass the logic to change the name in as a function to be run after the `slideToggle()` has completed.

```
...
var changeText = function() { <visibility text change logic> };
jQuery('#service_container').slideToggle('slow', changeText);
...
```

EDIT: reference saved fiddle.

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/rqGBb/1/

If you want the text to change immediately on click, you'll have to track the 'show/hide' status yourself in a variable, hang off the element, or test visibility in an outer `if` block.